# Can we add email notifications of new posts?

Tags: feature-request

I'd like to have to avoid polling ui.stackexchange x times a day but would pref email immediate notification when someone posts a new question as I'd like to have a crack at all of them, or at least those with a certain tag.

Anyone know how I can do this? I guess some kind of RSS polling might do the trick.

Comment: Why not use the RSS feed directly?

Comment: Because I have to poll. Feed My Inbox looks like it will do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [Feed My Inbox](http://www.feedmyinbox.com/) or a [similar service](http://www.google.com/search?q=rss+to+email).